# Receive trigger when active NSView focus changes

Tags: macos, nsview, nsnotifications

I'm surprised that I haven't been able to find an answer for this from searching.  So if there is a page describing how to do this, let me know, but I've been unable to find it.

I have 3 sibling `NSOutlineView`s all inside an `NSSplitView` I have added observers for `NSOutlineViewSelectionDidChange` which, when triggered update an `NSTextView` editor. I even test for negative row values to indicate that the user has unselected the row and clear the text.

The `NSOutlineViews` are connected to custom datasource objects and the `NSSplitView` is created by my custom `NSWindowController` in turn created by my custom `NSDocument` and  custom `NSDocumentController` (I'm not using `.nib`s)

However I cannot seem to receive triggers for the `NSOutlineView`s changing their active status, it works if the user selects a different row in a different `NSOutlineView`, as the *selection has changed* but if they click the selected row of a different view, I don't receive any event or notification that anything has changed.  Visually I can see the change as the row selection highlight colour changes from coloured to grey, in the outline view that has lost focus and the selection row colour changes from grey to coloured in the newly activated view.

I've tried to catch `mouseDown` events, tried becoming first responder, tried observing changes in the `NSSplitView`  I've been right through the `NSObject` hierarchy from `NSOutlineView` to `NSResponder` looking for the appropriate notification or method.  I found deprecated documentation regarding a focus change notification.  I've tried combinations of nsview, nsnotification, nsoutlineview and various actions in google but can't find the 'this is how you do it'

**EDIT:**
this is the code I've added to my NSOutlineView subclass (along with prototypes in the headers) to become first responder, but it is never triggered.

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder { return YES; }
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    NSLog(@"becomefirstResponder %@",self);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: subclassing and overriding becomeFirstResponder() should be what you are looking for

Comment: Check if you can catch symbolic bp with lldb `b +[_NSAutomaticFocusRing hideForView:]`

Comment: I'm not sure if I've created that breakpoint properly as it doesn't stop. Sorry I'm not too familiar with symbolic breaks.  So that string `b +[_NSAutomaticFocusRing hideForView:]` is the Symbol, no module, no condition, ignore 0 times, no action and no automatic continue.  Cheers Thanks.

Comment: `b +[_NSAutomaticFocusRing hideForView:]` is the debugger command line command, `+[_NSAutomaticFocusRing hideForView:]` is the symbol.

Comment: Try a breakpoint on `-[NSTableView becomeFirstResponder]`.

Comment: If you override `acceptsFirstResponder` and/or `becomeFirstResponder` then call `super`.

Comment: Simple type `b +[_NSAutomaticFocusRing hideForView:]` as one single lldb command. It will set a symbolic breakpoint and there is chance it will give you a meaningful stacktrace when hit.

Comment: Got it thanks.  I was using lldb from within Xcode and it has GUI alternatives. The breakpoint is working now.